# How to change the body background around plotly figure when rendered in browser?

Tags: python, browser, plotly, rendering, plotly-python

I was wondering if anyone knows how to remove this white border in firefox (or also chrome, doesn't matter) when I render a Scatter3d plot with plotly (python) for the browser. I already tried changing the margin to 0 but that did no change to the border. It seems like this white border is created around the actual figure by plotly. Is there any way to change/remove this? It is a little annoying when everything is dark except for this very white border around the whole figure. When I change the paper background color, then the dark background switches to whatever color I choose, but the white border stays as it is.

Thanks a lot in advance!

[image]

Comment: Could you please add any code to replicate your work and we can help?

Comment: This is just the margin of the body.

Comment: You can change the style of html page manually by adding `<html style="background-color:black">`

Comment: @Hamzah thanks, that was it! Is there any way to set the background color of the html body from python? I don't want to edit the webpage every single time I generate a new plot.

Comment: I was looking a solution for you, but unfortunately I did not find. You cannot style the exported html page. You can ask in the forum of Plotly community if you can get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Hamzah and @EricLavault for your help!

I managed to find a solution here: https://community.plotly.com/t/show-tell-plotly-graph-background-color-in-html-file-with-css-style/43223

For using it in Ubuntu I just had to replace the
`os.startfile(output_file)`
with
`webbrowser.open('file://' + os.path.realpath(output_file))`

Now there's no white border anymore! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I discovered an easier way to solve your problem. You can use JavaScript to change the color of the body of HTML file by using `post_script` attribute as follows:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',color='petal_length')

fig.update_layout( paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,255)' )
 
js = '''document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000"; ''' #<---- this is the JS code

fig.show(renderer="browser",post_script=[js])
```

[image]